# Can we use Vlookup function in python?

Tags: python, excel

I am attaching a sample excel file containing the data.In column E i have used vlookup.Can we do the same using python?

Please let me know..It will be a great help

Comment: you can use pandas `join` or `mege`

Comment: Can you provice an example of code  and/or example or data you're using to test your code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python has a popular library called `pandas`. It converts the excel file into a close representation called `DataFrame`.

While you cannot use cell wise formulas, pandas gives you alternatives similar to vlookup/hlookups.

You can use `join`, `group_by` and `merge`.

This article [How to Do a vLookup in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-do-a-vlookup-in-python-using-pandas/) will also help you directly.